# Caching issue with Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, browser-cache

I am working on an ASP.NET/MVC4 app and I fetch data continuously and my problem is related to caching.

The problem is that when I click on a particular link in my application it works fine, but sometimes it automatically redirects to the INDEX page that is the default page.

I surfed around about this problem and found that it's a problem in Mozilla that it maintains caching of every link. But sometimes some weird things happen and it automatically redirects a particular link to the INDEX page (`301 Permanently REMOVED`) and also stores it in the cache such that now every time I click on that link it always redirects me to the INDEX page that's been cached.

So now I have to clear the cache in my browser every time I face this problem.

How can I make it not automatically redirect to the cached INDEX page?

Comment: You need to figure out why your app is returning 301s. This is **not** standard behaviour, so you need to take a look at what you are doing. That Mozilla is caching the redirect is also standard behaviour, and is detailed in RFC2616 "This response is cacheable unless indicated otherwise. " If the redirect should not be permanent, then the app should be returning 302, not 301.

Comment: What are you redirecting to in the action you're calling and how are you doing it? Firefox and Chrome handle it different than IE.

Comment: thanks spender and BigM for instant reply,but i am not not manually redirecting it to INDEX page,but its automatically sending it to INDEX page if i pass some more time with application and at that time browser stores it in caching as 301, and then every time it redirects me to INDEX page as its cached. so i am not getting what to do

Comment: Have you tried 'Clear Cache' option ?

Answer (score 1):

You should really expand on what exactly is happening at that `particular link` you mention because well it should not 301 redirect unless your telling it to.

Also you say `I fetch data continuously`. What does this mean to us? Why is this important to know? Explain if this changes the link or the data? Are you 404ing the older data or something? That could possibly explain why you 301 back to your index.

Now with the limited information we have been given by you... if you want to prevent firefox from caching your urls/redirects simply make your url have a querystring that updates which each request. Like using a timestamp.

For example: `http://example.com/return-data.asp?timestamp=1350668920`

Then each time you `continuously fetch data` update the page's link accordingly

For example: `http://example.com/return-data.asp?timestamp=1350669084`

Comment: "I fetch data continuously" that means its not problem everytime. i am geting proper page most of the time,but only sometime this probmel occurs. that still is a proble.i still dont get any solution. i dont kno its problem of MVC redirection ? i even set routiong confi. but not get solution. i am not manually redirection any link that force firefox to set 301 flag.even i have also marked that its expire time chnage to "No expiration time".